# How to make a WPF TabControl with Materials Design type look without using MaterialDesignThemes?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, tabcontrol, material-design-in-xaml

I want to make a WPF window app and add a Materials Design'ish TabControl but without using MaterialDesignThemes. I'm using Sharpdevelop[which is discontinued, I know] & .NET 4.5. Dont judge me :). I'm not able to use MaterialDesignThemes, when I try it I get the error

[image: error_screenshot]

Has anyone ever done something like this, if yes, can you share ?

Comment: Why can't you use MaterialDesignThemes?

Comment: @mm8 I've updated my post, you can check.

Comment: That's not the material design nuget package. https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/wiki/Super-Quick-Start

Comment: There will be minimum visual studio and .net framework requirements. The fact you're targetting the obsolete .net4.5 makes me wonder what version of visual studio you have.

Comment: @Andy I'm not using visual studio but sharpdevelop (I mentioned it in my question) & I know .net4.5 is obsolete but most of the program that I make works fine. Visual studio takes way too much space of HDD where sharpdevelop takes only 50 MB. But unfortunately it was discontinued on 2016 & I cannot make it use anything higher than .net4.5.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1:** Upgrade your project to .NET Framework 4.5.2 or later, preferably at least 4.6.2 since version 4.5.2, 4.6, and 4.6.1 will officially reach end of support on April 26, 2022.

**Option 2:** Copy the styles for the `TabControl` and `TabItem` from [GitHub](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/73187efac48310a8f01bd44127a816ddffb6d9e5/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.TabControl.xaml), and edit them as per your requirements before you apply them to your controls.

Note that you will have to remove all Material Design specific stuff, such as `ColorZone` and `Ripple` elements, from the templates which till certainly affect the appearance so I strongly recommend the first option.